# Change image of a button in a datagrid cell when it is clicked - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which contains a Datagrid consisting of a column of buttons. The respective XAML code is as follows.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Closed" Width="60">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image>
                        <Image.Source>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ImageConverter}"
                                  ConverterParameter="Closed">
                                <Binding Path="IsClosed"/>
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.TickImage" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.CrossImage" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Button.Content>
                <Button.Command>
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.ClosedClicked" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                </Button.Command>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The `TickImage` and `CrossImage` are image sources either of which is selected based on the value of `IsClosed` .
Now in the ViewModel I need to write a code to toggle images(b/w `TickImage` and `CrossImage` ) when the button is clicked. In other words, I need a way to simultaneously bind the Button with an `ICommand` and a `BitmapImage` variable.

Please help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your `IsClosed` is just a toggle to know if button was pressed or release then you can achieve this by just using triggers like below:

```
 <ToggleButton>
     <ToggleButton.Content>
         <Image>
            <Image.Style>
              <Style TargerType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path="DataContext.TickImage" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                 <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToggleButton}}" Value="true">
                         <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path="DataContext.CrossImage" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
             </Image.Style>
            </Image>
          </ToggleButton.Content> 
        </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: The `Setter` and the `Style.Triggers` tag must be within the `Style` tag inside `Image.Style` . Even after that the following error occurs: `Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Source'.`

Comment: will need to give target type.. i wrote  the code without designer hence missed it :) updated the answer

Comment: yeah on clicking the image does toggle...but it reverts back to the original image on MouseUp